# EF Core 7.0 Error: "Add the entity seed to 'X' and specify the foreign key values" when already specified

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am having trouble seeding unidirectional relationships. The seeding looks as follows:

- User 1-->* Post

I'm receive this error on configuration

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The seed entity for entity type 'User' with the key value 'Id:1' cannot be added because it has the navigation 'Posts' set. To seed relationships, add the entity seed to 'Post' and specify the foreign key values {'UserId'}.

This error makes no sense to me, as I am already explicitly specifying the foreign key value **Post.UserId**...

*Any help is much appreciated!*

Here is my configuration

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Models.User>()
        .HasMany(user => user.Posts)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(post => post.UserId)
        .IsRequired(false);

    Models.User user = new() { Id = 1, Username = "user" };
    Models.Post post = new() { Id = 1, Body = "Hello from the other side", UserId = 1 };
    user.Posts.Add(post);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Models.User>().HasData(user);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Post>().HasData(post);
}
```

And here are my class definitions

```cs
public abstract class Base
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime? UpdateAt { get; set; }
}

public class Post : Base
{
    [Required] public string Body { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User : Base
{
    [Required] public string Username { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Post.UserId))] public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } = new List<Post>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error in my implementation for anyone experiencing the same.

In the creation phase, you are not supposed to populate virtual collections, in this case `User.Posts`, as the foreign key is what EF uses to populate the collections later on. Basicailly remove `user.Posts.Add(post);`

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Models.User>()
        .HasMany(user => user.Posts)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(post => post.UserId)
        .IsRequired(false);

    Models.User user = new() { Id = 1, Username = "user" };
    Models.Post post = new() { Id = 1, Body = "Hello from the other side", UserId = 1 };

    modelBuilder.Entity<Models.User>().HasData(user);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Models.Post>().HasData(post);
}
```

On top of that, EF implements lazy loading behind the scenes, so when fetching data from the DB, you must include your virtual collections to populate them. This is in `repositories/User.cs`:

```cs
public static Models.User? Get(string username)
{
    using Contexts.Main context = new();
    return context.Users.Include(user => user.Posts).SingleOrDefault(user => user.Username == username);
}
```